# Is there a way to do IntervalMatch in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, transformation

Im trying to do an IntervalMatch from the following link in ADF:
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2022/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/IntervalMatch.htm

Is there an activity (Join, ...) or another way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Comment: My Data is pretty close to the one in the Link. I sadly have no attempt because I have no clue how to approach this.

Comment: You can use  **JOIN transformation** in Data flow.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repro this in ADF data flow with sample inputs and below is the approach.

**Input tables:**
*Event_log:*

| Time | Event | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0:00 | 0 | Start of shift 1 |
| 1:18 | 1 | Line stop |
| 2:23 | 2 | Line restart 50% |
| 4:15 | 3 | Line speed 100% |
| 8:00 | 4 | Start of shift 2 |
| 11:43 | 5 | End of production |

*Order_log:*

| Start | End | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1:00 | 03:35 | A |
| 2:30 | 07:58 | B |
| 3:04 | 10:27 | C |
| 7:23 | 11:43 | D |

- Source transformations (source1 and source2) are taken for the above tables.
- Join transformation is taken. In Join settings

  - Source1 *(Event Log)* is taken as Left stream and Source2 *(Order_log)* is taken as right stream.
  - Join type is given as *Right Outer*.
  - Joining conditions are **Start<=Time and End>=Time**.

[image]

**Output of Join Transformation:**

| Start | End | Order | Time | Event | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | 0:00 | 0 | Start of shift 1 |
| 1:00 | 3:35 | A | 1:18 | 1 | Line stop |
| 1:00 | 3:35 | A | 2:23 | 2 | Line restart 50% |
| 2:30 | 7:58 | B | 4:15 | 3 | Line speed 100% |
| 3:04 | 10:27 | C | 4:15 | 3 | Line speed 100% |
| 3:04 | 10:27 | C | 8:00 | 4 | Start of shift 2 |
| 7:23 | 11:43 | D | 8:00 | 4 | Start of shift 2 |
| 7:23 | 11:43 | D | 11:43 | 5 | End of production |

[image]